# Why does spring-boot not support PEM encoded CA certs in application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, x509, pem

Spring boot allows you to configure ssl in application properties as explain in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl), however it does not support PEM encoded CA certs.

I know you can convert PEM encoded CA certs with openssl and then import them into a keystore in order to use them for configuring https but it will be nice if you could directly refer to PEM certificates in your application configuration.

This will be particularly useful for situations where you have automated renewal of certificates, lets say with certbot and you do not want to have to update your keystore as well.

Is there any reason why this is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to import a private key for use in Java.

On some java instances, using the built in keystore system is the default way of doing those things.

Here is a code snippet to get the default store type:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.print(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDsIgFEV3vuKNdJAf6OpmnHAzDq/02VApEHg0IabfjpjodJNzz81dccdTiOTX@dWa3WJIDGuHKpMpyXJVF6qaQ6JRiFgmZw0YhznDFa0XbwHwo5mRe@zBzrD1TmpO1i/3B2Ba8tDFrwyga2baVCisYhdY/g/UQnymJxbHtxpJDsPYB4c4WvsA) will give you `jks` like some other online java code runners.

So since it is the default java way, there is just not enough added value for the spring framework in changing that.

Some more links:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html
- https://serverfault.com/a/9717/465260

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of this but I was more looking for a way that this could be build in to the applications properties instead of having to write specific classes for it